# How to output "error line number" in ruby exception handling?

Tags: ruby, exception, error-handling

I have the below sample code:

```rb
begin
  # some code
  # some code
  # some code
rescue => error
   puts error
```

I get the error `"string not matched"` Which doesn't tell you where the error occured. But when I remove the exception handling wrapper I get:

```
my_script.rb:20:in `[]=': string not matched (IndexError)
        from my_script.rb:20:in `block in my_func'
        from my_script.rb:18:in `each'
        from my_script.rb:18:in `my_func'
        from my_script.rb:66:in `<main>'
```

Which is more detailed. How can I print a more detailed error message?

Comment: Since everything in ruby is an object the `error` is no different. Every object has its own methods so you can see how to get these details from the docs. The parent of all errors is [`Exception`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Exception.html#method-i-backtrace) and it provides methods for viewing things like the backtrace which appears to be what you are referring to as more detailed.

Comment: @engineersmnky I tried outputting `error.full_message`. That seems to give me exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: probably you need to play with `caller`. This oblect contains array of call stack with file names and line numbers, as you want.